# Wicket CheckBoxMultipleChoice

Tags: wicket

How to change css style of  Rendered html of CheckBoxMultipleChoice? CheckBoxMultipleChoice renders this html output by default but i want to  change css style of this rendered output

```
<div class="ca-info__cat-roles js-roles-1 expanded" wicket:id="categories" id="categoriesb">
    <input name="categories" type="checkbox" value="819" id="categoriesb categories_819">
    <label for="categoriesb-categories_819">index&gt;root&gt;CategoryCatalog.png&gt;9</label>
    <input name="categories" type="checkbox" value="829" id="categoriesb-categories_829">
    <label for="categoriesb-categories_829">index&gt;root&gt;tv.png&gt;9</label>
</div>
```

I want to change styles of inputs and labels, but i don't know how to do it with CheckBoxMultipleChoice.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this way. There are two ways

1. Add CSS in html page itself . inside `style` tag add your style like below but this will affect other component if you have same style.

   ```
   .ca-info__cat-roles js-roles-1.expanded label{
       // Your style for label
    }       
   .ca-info__cat-roles js-roles-1.expanded input{
       // Your style for input 
    }
   ```

2.Another way  You can [override#appendHtml](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/CheckBoxMultipleChoice.html#appendOptionHtml(org.apache.wicket.util.string.AppendingStringBuffer,%20T,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) and derive your own style for check box (e.g)`buffer.append("class=\"yourStyleclass\"");`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to use custom css for you component you have to use setSuffix() and setPrefix() methods, like this:

```
checkboxes = new CheckBoxMultipleChoice<>("checkboxes", value);
checkboxes.setSuffix("<br/>");
```